# Bug in Louisiana Economic Development Ad?

Tags: actionscript

I was reading the June 2011 issue of Wired magazine the other day, and I came across an ad for Louisiana Economic Development, presumably written in ActionScript.

I originally thought that it was a clever ad, but after looking into it, it seems like there's a fairly obvious bug in the code.

[image: LED Ad]

Is it just me, or should that `break` be a `return`?

Comment: It should be a return unless the idea is that regardless of whether innovator has any of the listed interests they should still go to the listed URL...  but that isn't the only bug.  Apparently they can't decide whether they're writing AS2 or AS3, as the lowercase void and the existence of uint indicates AS3 but navigateToURL only exists in AS2.  On the other hand, maybe they've declared a function elsewhere in their code with the name navigateToURL out of nostalgia.

Comment: I think you might be just the kind of guy they'd like to have check out opportunities in Louisiana - //Do you see the opportunity? Then again, maybe it's not a bug and they just want everyone to check out Louisiana opportunities.

Comment: Oh, but despite the bug and ambiguous scripting language error, I have to give them credit for storing var n:uint = interests.length;  That does in fact offer a runtime performance boost in ActionScript... not that it matters for a 3 element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd call it a bug, since the desired outcome would most likely be to navigate to the URL if any one of those interests is held and do nothing if none of them are. As such, I would change the logic to the following (ignoring for the moment the issues mentioned in the comment from scriptocalypse):

```
if (this.innovator.hasInterestIn(interest[i])){
    navigateToURL("www.OpportunityLouisiana.com/digital");
    return;
}
```

Of course, this wouldn't look as good in an ad, since the URL wouldn't be prominently displayed at the bottom of the code. Perhaps a better alternative would be to organize the logic in the loop like this:

```
if (this.innovator.hasInterestIn(interest[i])){
    break;
} else if (i == n-1){
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't agree, the desired outcome is probably to navigate to the URL if all three are true, not just one of them. Otherwise the loop is just wrong on a new level.

Comment: @vakio: You make a good point. If that's the case, then the `break;` should definitely be a `return;`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't call it a bug as much as faulty logic...the break will get you out of the loop, but if you enter that function you're navigating to that URL, whether you're interested in all those things or not.

Comment: "Wouldn't call it a bug as much as faulty logic..." - I'm using that in my next bug meeting.

Comment: Yeah...after I posted this I thought to myself, faulty logic resulting in unintended consequences pretty much constitutes a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that should be a return.  Right now, as the code stands, navigatetoUrl will fire even if the user has none of the interests.