# Passing a constant integer when function expects a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

What's the best/most cannonical way of passing in a constant integer value to a function that expects a pointer?

For example, the `write` function

```
write (int filedes, const void *buffer, size_t size);
```

Let's say I just want to write a single byte (a 1), I would think this:

```
write (fd, 1, 1);
```

but I obviously get the warning

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'write' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

---

I know I can do

```
int i = 1;
write (fd, &i, 1);
```

but is that necessary? What's the most correct way of doing this without the need of declaring/initializing a new variable?

Comment: Your "I know I can do ..." example is incorrect. You want to say `char i = 1; write(fd, &i, 1);`.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, you're right about the char. I'm only ever writing a 1 or a 0 in this case (it's a control line) so I guess I overlooked the fact that it's incorrect-but-working.

Comment: let me guess ... you have a little endian machine, right?

Comment: "incorrect-but-working" - something else I'll try to work into a bug triage (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114684/bug-in-louisiana-economic-development-ad/6114778#6114778). Soon I'll be knocking 'em dead in that meeting.

Comment: Super necro-post, but I'll add that I would make a second function (call it "put", for example) that only writes one byte and does whatever typecasting nonsense in necessary to make this work. In my libraries with any sort of read/write operation, I usually make a singular verb (put / get / read / write) for a single byte (or object) and plural (puts / gets / reads / writes) for multiple that require a buffer and length. You could also do the stdlib way and do "put" and "putn" ... I just find that a bit ugly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C89/90 you can't generally do it without declaring a new variable. The thing about pointers in C is that they always point to lvalues. Lvalue is something that has a location in memory. So, in order to supply the proper argument to your function, you need something that has a location in memory. That normally requires a definition, i.e. an object, a variable. Constants in C are not lvalues, so you can't use a constant there. Things that lie somewhat in between constants and variables are *literals*. C89/90 has only one kind of literal: *string literal*. String literals are lvalues, but not variables. So, you can use a string literal as the second argument of `write`.

In C99 the notion of literal was extended beyond string literals. In C99 you can also use *compound literals* for that purpose, which also happen to be lvalues. In your example you can call your function as

```
write(fd, (char[]) { 1 }, 1)
```

But this feature is only available in C99.

Comment: +1, I didn't know this. Too bad GCC still defaults to C90, but at least Intel C compiles this without extra flags.

Comment: Nice. To spell out the C90 solution described: `write( fd, "\x1", 1);`.  I might actually use that sometime; I'm not sure if I'm happy about that.

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing that C99 method? Other than the obvious fact that you don't need an extra variable? That is, over say @Michael Burr's version with the string constant?

Comment: I selected this as it is the most direct answer to my question. However, I probably wouldn't use this method unless there's a really good argument for it, which I don't see there being.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's necessary. There's no other way to do this in C that is equally clear, since you can't take the address of/get a pointer to a temporary.

(And, as @rob already said, you should take the address of a `char`. Your example is non-portable.)

**EDIT**: See @AndreyT's answer and set your compiler to C99 mode.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case you cite, you can do this:

```
write(fd, "\001", 1);
```

But, more generally, you must do that about which you are complaining. You must declare an object before taking its address:

```
 SomeType i;
 SomeFUnction(&i);
```

Comment: Note that my answer only correct w.r.t C90. For a good example of how to use new-fangled C99, see @AndreyT.

Comment: I think this is clearer than the C99 option (and will work in C90, C99, or C++).  I'm not sure I'd endorse using it. But as I alluded to in a comment to AndreyT's answer, now that I've seen it I probably will.

Answer (score 1):

An integer isn't a pointer. If you pass it a one, it will dereference virtual address 1 and die. You must make that variable and pass its address.

Answer (score 1):

Write requires an address as is second parameter - live with it.

Comment: I have no problem "living with it". I was just curious since I feel like this is a fairly common case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drprintf()` which prints to a file descriptor. It is similar to `fprintf()` which prints to a `FILE *`.

```
int dprintf(int fd, const char *format, ...);
```

See `man 3 dprintf` for details.

*The  functions  dprintf()  and  vdprintf()  (as  found  in  the  glibc2 library) are exact analogs of fprintf(3) and vfprintf(3), except that they output to a file descriptor fd instead  of  to  a  stdio stream.*

It is POSIX.1 compliant, not universal.

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: You want to write a single byte without using a temporary variable. You can do that: `dprintf(fd,"%c",1);`.

Comment: Ah, I was spacing out. Since I'm writing to a serial line, I'm pretty set on using `write` instead of the higher level io functions. As it's my understanding that there is less buffering involved than in `fprintf` and the like (unless I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

```
write(var, new int(4))
```

This seems to work. Not sure how good this is as I haven't used c++ that much.
Let me know if this is a bad way to do this.

Comment: You just successfully created a memory leak.